# Oracle Database Project Items VS2013 and ODP.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2013, odp.net

Is there a way to create the script files using Oracle file extension like PKS, PKB, etc. and still have ODP/VS treat them like the SQL files?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the editor for each extension in the Visual Studio settings:

[image]

Just enter the extension (sans the `.`) and the editor to use then click "add". This basically allows you to set the editor for any file type, as long as Visual Studio has an editor available.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't seem to work. I will look at it again.